# Implement interface using concrete implementations of abstract interface members

Tags: c#

Is there a specific reason why the following is not possible?

```
class ClassOfInts : IHaveInts
{
    public MyInt IntHolder { get; }
    // This solves my use case but i'm unsure why this is necessary
    // IInt IHaveInts.IntHolder { get => IntHolder; }
}

interface IHaveInts
{
    IInt IntHolder { get; }
}


class MyInt : IInt
{
    public int TheInt { get; }
}

interface IInt
{
    int TheInt { get; }
}
```

I would think that the above code successfully implements IHaveInts since MyInt implements IInt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a specific reason why the following is not possible?

Well, the short answer is: "because the C# specification doesn't allow it". Longer answers typically involve some amount of speculation as to what was in the thought process of the C# language designers. That makes such questions primarily opinion based.

However, they did make a deliberate choice that interface members have to be implemented *precisely* as declared, and that choice is why you can't do that. A likely reason behind that choice is that they would have to special-case read-only properties, because allowing the property to be implemented that way for a writeable property would be unsafe. Were they to allow that, you'd be able to assign *any* `IInt` value to the property which expects only `MyInt` values.

That said, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might be able to use generic type variance to support your scenario. This will compile fine:

```
public class ClassOfInts : IHaveInts<MyInt>
{
    public MyInt IntHolder { get; }
}

public interface IHaveInts<out T> where T : IInt
{
    T IntHolder { get; }
}
```

Declared that way, the following works fine:

```
static void M()
{
    IHaveInts<IInt> haveInts = new ClassOfInts();
}
```

This is semantically equivalent to what you were originally trying to do. That is, when using the interface type, you have a property of type `IInt`, but you want to implement that property with a member that returns a value of type `MyInt`.